# how to retrieve element from pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

i have many to many relationship between a job_seeker and job_offer (pivot table="job_seeker_job_offer)
and i have page which displays all the job offer for specific employer how to retrieve the number of job_seeker who attached to specific job_offer

the function which display the job offers

```
 public function show_jobs($id){
        // $categories=Category::all();
        $job_offer_all=Job_offer::all();
        $employer=Employer::find($id);
        $job_offers=Job_offer::where('employer_id',$employer_id)->with('employer')->get();
        return view('employer.my_jobs',compact('employer_id','employer','job_offers','n_applicant'));
       }
```

the function which attach the job seeker with job offer

```
public function send_offer($id,$employer_id,$offer_id){
    $job_seeker=Job_seeker::find($id);
    $job_offer=Job_offer::find($offer_id);
    $employer=Employer::find($employer_id);
    // Notification::route('mail', $employer->email)
    // ->notify(new submit_job_demand($job_seeker));
    $job_seeker->job_offer()->attach($job_offer->id);

    }
```

Comment: Why is job_seeker -> job_offer, many to many?

Comment: If you set up relationships correct, then you can use $job_offer->job_seeker;

Comment: @arun yes i want to implement this but only to retrieve the specific job offer im looking for

Comment: @ijames because every job_seeker can have many job_offers and  vice_versa

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the relationship setup in both directions, you can use the `withCount` method to get a count of the relationship:

```
$jobOffers = JobOffer::where('employer_id', $employer_id)
    ->withCount('job_seekers')
    ->with('employer')
    ->get();

foreach ($jobOffers as $offer) {
    echo $offer->job_seekers_count;
}
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)